# building a full duplex pipe in C

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I'm trying to make a full duplex pipe, it's a piece of my home work (i tell beforehand).
The scope of the homework is much much larger than this pipe, I just need it done so I could go on with the work. I paste here only the code that matters, i didn't paste the whole code.

```
#define READ_END 0
#define WRITE_END 1

int main()
{
    Folder* curFolder = (Folder*) malloc (sizeof(Folder));
    assert(curFolder != NULL);

    initFolder(curFolder, NULL, "root");
    makeDir(curFolder, "test");

    return 0;
}

Pipe* createPipe()
{
    Pipe* p = (Pipe*) malloc (sizeof(Pipe));
    assert(p != NULL);

    pipe( p->readPipe );
    pipe( p->writePipe );

    //close( p->readPipe[WRITE_END] );
    //close( p->writePipe[READ_END] );

    return p;
}

char* readMsg(FolderRef* folderHandle, char* buffer)
{
    read(folderHandle->pipe->readPipe[READ_END], buffer, PIPE_BUF);

    return buffer;
}

void sendMsg(FolderRef* folderHandle, char* msg)
{
    write(folderHandle->pipe->writePipe[WRITE_END], msg, strlen(msg) + 1);
}

void makeDir(Folder* curFolder, char* name)
{
    pid_t childId;
    char msg[PIPE_BUF];
    Pipe* con = createPipe();

    childId = fork();

    switch ( childId )
    {
        case -1: // error occurred
        {
            printf( "Error at fork in function makeDir.\n" );
            exit( 0 );
        }
        case 0: // son process
        {
            initFolder( curFolder, getFolderHandle( getppid(), con, "" ), name );
            readMsg(curFolder->parentFolder, msg);
            printf("%s\n", msg);
            sendMsg(curFolder->parentFolder, "roger roger");
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            insertFolder(&curFolder->folderList, getFolderHandle(childId, con, name));
            sendMsg(curFolder->folderList->folder, "test");
            readMsg(curFolder->folderList->folder, msg);
            printf("%s\n", msg);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

the result (for now) should be output on the screen:
test
roger roger

however I cant get it done. I seem to miss some little detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write to `pipe->writePipe[WRITE_END]` you need to read from `pipe->writePipe[READ_END]`. It seems that you try to read from `pipe->readPipe[READ_END]` but this is another pipe.

Comment: I guess you are right. I've already done this and got the first message to pass from the "father" process to the son. I'm still having trouble to send something back. It is crucial for the connection to be full duplex. I think I have to somehow do a cross over with those pipes, I just can't figure how.